# Binding Image.Source to property doesn't appear, in designer

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I want to bind the Source of an Image (in WinRT XAML) to the ImageSource property of a view model called ServiceEnvoy, which points to an image in my project's /Assets directory. Here is the view model:

```
public class ServiceEnvoy
{
    public ServiceEnvoy(string name, ImageSource source)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ImageSource = source;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; private set; }
}
```

Here is the XAML of the ListView I want to expose the view model:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Services}" 
          ...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> <!--Works fine-->
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/> <!--Does not-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

There's another complication, however: the view model is deserialized from JSON to be loaded onto the main page.

Here is the JSON I have so far:

```
{
    "Services": [
        {
            "Name": "OneDrive",
            "Image": "onedrive.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

A ServiceEnvoyExtractor class (found [here](http://pastebin.com/FnCMQTaS) on Pastebin) extracts the view model by appending `"ms-appx:///Assets/"` to `"Image"` and creating a Uri/BitmapImage out of that. I'm not sure if that was the problem, but I tried changing the JSON to `"Image": "/Assets/onedrive.png"` or `"ms-appx:///Assets/onedrive.png"` and rebuilding, but the designer still did not display the image. However, it works fine when I run it on my phone.

My `d:DataContext` is: `d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignData Source=/Data/ServiceRecords.json, Type=data:DesignableServiceEnvoyCollection}}"`

Comment: try to use public BitmapImage ImageSource { get; private set; } instead of public ImageSource ImageSource { get; private set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was rather simple.

After a few hours of frustrating myself with the type of the `ImageSource` and renaming it and testing other controls with it and fiddling around with the JSON, I realized that while its key was `"Image"`, I was binding to `"ImageSource"`.

That, and changing its directory to `"Assets/onedrive.png"` fixed the problem.

**EDIT:** The XAML also seemed to throw an error about how `ImageSource` properties could not be serialized; changing the property to type `string` fixed the problem.